# How to determine LUKS version on RHEL 7

Tags: rhel, luks

I have an encrypted volume using LUKS and am unsure whether it is LUKS1 or LUKS2.

Here's the lsblk output:

```
[acoder@rhel7 ~]# lsblk --fs
NAME                                            FSTYPE      LABEL UUID                                   MOUNTPOINT
sr0                                                                                                      
vda                                                                                                      
├─vda1                                          xfs               b05d3e82-d170-42d1-b0e1-a0a84e8722d6   /boot
├─vda2                                          vfat              841D-B7DD                              /boot/efi
└─vda3                                          LVM2_member       e1lbWc-iwdF-VJ9C-3nsz-NhrE-pGlH-8YgSy3 
  ├─rhel-06                                     crypto_LUKS       d718f899-1a0d-4bb3-b2b7-0a6c12606c78   
  │ └─luks-d718f899-1a0d-4bb3-b2b7-0a6c12606c78 xfs               2cea9ac7-95f2-48a4-8cf3-37ea9c6e9375   /
  ├─rhel-00                                     crypto_LUKS       8f3a9565-3767-4935-8730-fbe21c927a4d   
  │ └─luks-8f3a9565-3767-4935-8730-fbe21c927a4d swap              a914ceb3-5a2e-4d22-b8eb-30069087eee0   [SWAP]
  ├─rhel-02                                     crypto_LUKS       c7453246-6dd7-4cc7-bd5d-0d3518f0d35d   
  │ └─luks-c7453246-6dd7-4cc7-bd5d-0d3518f0d35d xfs               3ab1bbac-633d-4548-9a6c-61deae6f0e69   /usr
  ├─rhel-01                                     crypto_LUKS       15c73981-a4f2-484c-acfd-f09312143698   
  │ └─luks-15c73981-a4f2-484c-acfd-f09312143698 xfs               6059b317-ffd3-4ee7-9804-1f9988372464   /home
  ├─rhel-03                                     crypto_LUKS       3d401862-3a47-423a-8c9a-4505ca214d0f   
  │ └─luks-3d401862-3a47-423a-8c9a-4505ca214d0f xfs               35c1c30f-dd91-4bc6-9fe8-324b92cbd126   /var
  ├─rhel-04                                     crypto_LUKS       374cb4e2-a4ad-4c9a-9188-e3927166fada   
  │ └─luks-374cb4e2-a4ad-4c9a-9188-e3927166fada xfs               673979b8-88ed-4803-83ff-dce166f83d8a   /var/log
  ├─rhel-05                                     crypto_LUKS       5658d96d-1fb5-4e87-898f-31c7c8ba8de5   
  │ └─luks-5658d96d-1fb5-4e87-898f-31c7c8ba8de5 xfs               8ca6df73-c3af-44cc-9ba8-d370e47a0d5a   /var/log/audit
  ├─rhel-07                                     crypto_LUKS       4a7392cf-ede2-433e-b889-cf1d3cab16b5   
  │ └─luks-4a7392cf-ede2-433e-b889-cf1d3cab16b5 xfs               a0a11191-f488-43e9-90cb-802287d01569   /data/www
  └─rhel-08                                     crypto_LUKS       4cbfb84b-8747-45d4-99dc-a1d1f0100188   
    └─luks-4cbfb84b-8747-45d4-99dc-a1d1f0100188 xfs               15b5db1f-e6ad-4057-a0d9-780a08adb16c   /data/db
```

I tried issuing `cryptsetup luksDump dev`, but am not seeing any output:

```
[acoder@rhel7 ~]# cryptsetup luksDump /dev/vda
[acoder@rhel7 ~]# cryptsetup luksDump /dev/vda1
[acoder@rhel7 ~]# cryptsetup luksDump /dev/vda2
[acoder@rhel7 ~]# cryptsetup luksDump /dev/vda3
[acoder@rhel7 ~]#
```

RedHat [says](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/security_hardening/encrypting-block-devices-using-luks_security-hardening) RHEL8 uses LUKS2 by default, but the same page for [RHEL7](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/sec-encryption) does not specify type.

**EDIT 1**

Here is output from

`cryptsetup luksDump /dev/mapper/rhel-00`

```
# cryptsetup luksDump /dev/mapper/rhel-00
LUKS header information for /dev/mapper/rhel-00

Version:        1
Cipher name:    aes
Cipher mode:    xts-plain64
Hash spec:      sha1
Payload offset: 4096
MK bits:        512
MK digest:      b9 48 e2 bb 4e ae 70 9b c9 b5 b1 5e e6 9f ad fe 5c 58 15 b8 
MK salt:        40 27 f3 f9 f2 be 21 a1 25 a6 1a 21 0b 12 5a f2 
                ed cd c9 02 6e 36 d7 8e b1 90 96 86 c2 68 2c a6 
MK iterations:  64000
UUID:           8f3a9565-3767-4935-8730-fbe21c927a4d

Key Slot 0: ENABLED
    Iterations:             128255
    Salt:                   e2 e6 e1 a7 06 49 2b af e6 00 4f 6a e1 60 24 f1 
                            a2 2b 41 9f 4f 4b 65 a0 a4 10 1a 6c 72 97 56 50 
    Key material offset:    8
    AF stripes:             4000
Key Slot 1: DISABLED
Key Slot 2: DISABLED
Key Slot 3: DISABLED
Key Slot 4: DISABLED
Key Slot 5: DISABLED
Key Slot 6: DISABLED
Key Slot 7: DISABLED
```

If I run the same command on a RHEL 8 system, I am still showing "Version 1" so I'm not sure that is a reliable marker (per RHEL documentation, RedHat 8 uses LUKS2 by default).

Ultimately, I am working towards permanently decrypting the volumes on this system. I need to make sure what LUKS version I use before attempting to decrypt.

Is there another method to determine which LUKS version this system is using?

Comment: is there a /dev/rhel/00 or /dev/mapper/rhel-00 etc.? does luksDump work for those?

Comment: Yes, there is - I think I have what I need? Adding to my question since it's a lot of text.

Comment: So I also checked a RHEL8 system which RedHat says uses LUKS2 by default, and the version shown in cryptsetup luksDump DEV shows `Version 1`. So I'm unsure if that is referring to the LUKS type or not.

Comment: it's luks 1, yeah